# Lattice of Sperner families

Tags: lattice-orders

Given a set $S$, I am interested in the set $U$, constructed in the following way:

A set $u$ is a member of $U$ if and only if:

1. The elements of $u$ are subsets of $S$;
2. No element of $u$ is a subset of another element of $u$;
3. Every element of $S$ is a member of at least one element of $u$.

This is similar to the set of partitions of $S$ but is not the same. We obtain the set of partitions if we strengthen condition 3 to say that every element of $S$ is in *exactly* one element of $u$, rather than at least one.

As Erick Wong helpfully points out, each member of $U$ forms a [Sperner family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner_family).

For example, if $S=\{A,B,C\}$ then
$$
\begin{align}
U = \{&\\
&\{\{A\},\{B\},\{C\}\},\\
&\{\{A,B\},\{C\}\},\\
&\{\{B,C\},\{A\}\},\\
&\{\{A,C\},\{B\}\},\\
&\{\{A,B\},\{A,C\}\},\\
&\{\{A,B\},\{B,C\}\},\\
&\{\{A,C\},\{B,C\}\},\\
&\{\{A,B,C\}\}\\
\}.
\end{align}
$$

My question is simply whether this construction has a name, and whether there are any areas of mathematics where it arises or plays an important role. If it appears without condition 3 I'm interested in that as well.

More specifically, this set can be given a lattice structure. For $u,v\in U$ we say that $u\subseteq v$ if every member of $u$ is either a member of $v$ or a subset of a member of $v$. What I really want to understand is the structure of this lattice, and I'm interested in anything that has been written or can be said about that.

Comment: Looks like the set of partitions of $S$.

Comment: @Wuestenfux in the set of partitions, condition 3 would be replaced by "every element of $S$ is a member of *exactly* one element of $u$", rather than at least one. (I'll edit that into the question.)

Comment: Without condition 3 this is called a [Sperner family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner_family), after Sperner's theorem which establishes a tight upper bound on the cardinality of $u$.  The cardinality of $U$ (after relaxing the problem to remove condition 3) as a function of $|S|$ is apparently called the [Dedekind number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number).

Comment: @ErickWong thanks, that's very helpful - it's given me a new title for the question

Answer (score 0):

Such families are studied in the literature. What you are asking for is a **Sperner** family $U$ that cover the base set $S$.

Without condition 3 ($S$ covers $U$), lattice structure of such families are studied. For example search on 'Maximal antichains'. **Antichain** is a generalization of the notion of Sperner family. An antichain of a poset $P$ is a subset of $P$ containing pairwise incomparable elements. It is related to the notion of **completely seperating system (CSS)**.

In a paper on antichains, I have seen this covering condition along with intersecting condition (ie, every 2 members of $U$ gives nonempty intersection). May be, there is a paper discussing covering condition alone ( i have a vague memory of seeing one). I shall update the answer giving names of those papers as soon as I go through them again.

Thank you